# 2n2222 can not make it work as gate

Tags: arduino, transistors, relay, raspberry-pi, logic-gates

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIAZ77.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to make a simple switch with the 2N2222, so i can send 5 volts from a 3.3 V output pin on an arduino/raspberry pi.

I have constructed the circuit in the simulator, and it works.

In the real circuit, instead of VM1, I have placed a LED where the positive is after the diode and the negative is connected to ground.

So i was expecting, when i close the switch then the led should close instead of this the real circuit keeps the led on and the voltage is the same.

What do i miss here? Probably it is something very easy but i can not figure it out.

Comment: The base floats when your switch is open.

Comment: And? Can it trigger while it floats(i expect no)? but if triggers it should close the led. My problem is that when close the switch and the 3.3v run to the 1.2kohms and the 2n2222 it does not trigger. So what do you exactly propose to do. Probably i do not understant what you are saying.Sorry in advance

Comment: You need to pull the base *down* for the case where the switch is open (which Scott hinted at). Try 10k.

Comment: ok i will try. one more comment the switch basically is a output pin of the arduino/rasberry

Comment: sorry it did not work. i took out the 1.2k and place a 10k resistor i measured it i get from pinout the same resistance until the base of transistor. but it does not trigger. Write now i am using as pin the 3.3v out and i trigger it manually

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough; you need to *keep* the 1.2k series base resistor and *add* a 10k resistor from the base to ground.

Comment: sorry i did not get it, but i tested this also i places the 1.2k back and i placed after this a 10k that goes to ground. it did not work

Comment: What does "not work" mean in this last case?  Didn't turn on, or won't turn off?

Comment: I have updated also the schematic. The problem is that it does not turn off. When switch is closed like in the schematic the led does not turn off

Comment: The Circuitlab simulation runs perfectly.  Open the switch and run it, then close the switch and look at the difference.

Comment: When the switch is closed, the LED is on.  When open, the LED is off.

Comment: the sim run's i aggree when switch is pressed the led is off and when the switch is released then it is On , the circuit does not do it.

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what I said.  You must be running the sim wrong.  Change the switch position, THEN run the sim.  The numbers correspond to the way you just edited the switch.

Comment: This is the complete case now. When i have the switch closed 3.3v is applied then the sim shows that the led should be off, which is what i want but real circuit does not work like this. And when switch is open so no volts are applied to base (current) then the led should be base on sim On and this is correct also in real life. So the problem is on triggering the base.

Comment: I am not placing the led in series to cut the circuit i place it in parallel cause i wait that it should be as you see 77mV, like a not gate

Comment: Come on -- you keep changing things!!! Put your LED where it belongs -- in series with the emitter, where D1 is.

Comment: Sorry i propably did not explain it from the beginning sorry. This is the place. I want to work like a not gate, so i give power to the base and then i have 0Volts at the output and when i close the pin i have 5 volts at the output, this is why i was speaking about VM1, i said about led but i did not exactly specify how it is placed so my mistake

Comment: Then yes, if you're talking about producing a voltage, and not something that can drive a current load like an LED, the configuration you're using is inverting.  If that doesn't work, go with a pnp transistor

Answer (score 2):

Your original question was confusing. I have edited your question, hopefully to make it clear. So what you are building is a transistor inverting switch, and you want to turn the LED (D2) on and off by shorting it via the transistor, and the transistor is controlled by an output pin of an Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

There are several potential problems,

1. Make sure your real circuit is identical to your schematics, and your wiring is correct. You can move the voltmeters to anywhere you want, but not other components. Nothing can be answered if you are working on a different circuit than what you've showed here.
2. When your output is HIGH, are your 3.3 V output sourcing enough current to turn the transistor on?

   - Measure the voltage between your output and ground, you should see 3.3 V if the output is HIGH.
   - If you are using a 1200 ohm resistor, the base current is approximately 2 mA (3.3 V / 1200 Ω = 2.75 mA, without considering the pull-down resistor and emitter resistance). So you should be able to see roughly a 2 V voltage across your base resistor R1, similarly, between the collector of the transistor and ground, you should see a very low voltage, less than 1 V.
   - If you are not seeing what you expected to see, it means your output is not sourcing current correctly, or the transistor is defective, try another transistor first (it's unlikely to solve your problem, but better to double check). To isolate the potential problem of the output pin and programming, disconnect your R1 from the output, and try using a jumper wire to connect R1 directly to the 3.3 volt power pin (remember, do not remove R1), and see if you can turn the LED off.
   - A common mistake in microcontroller is forgetting that the pin was set to INPUT, then attempting to use it as an OUTPUT. It may appear to work when you probe it with a high-impedance voltmeter or scope, but it cannot source any current.
3. If you are building a low-side switch to turn D2 on and off, why did you put the D2 between collector and ground? If the transistor is on, R1 & D1 are shorted to ground by the transistor, and the current consumption is 400 mA, (5 V - 0.7 V) / 100 Ω = 430 mA. If your transistor is off, R1 & D1 are connected to ground by D2, and depends on the color of the LED, the current consumption is (5 V - 0.7 V - 2 V) / 100 Ω = 230 mA or so. You are wasting power for no reason.

   - Normally, NPN transistor is used as a low-side switch, the load you are trying to switch is connected between the +5 V and collector.
   - Similarly, what is the purpose of D1? Are you trying to use D1 to drop additional voltage to light the LED? Why can't you use a bigger resistor? Because you can't find it?

Comment: When i set the base to 3.3v with the resistor etc shouldn't the led turn off? this is the question. i understand that the pins in arduino... have pull -up or pull-down so Low mean ground and high means 3.3v. but my problem is not that the led is turn off with i have a LOW in output pin but that the led does not turn off when i have HIGH in the output pin

Comment: @kyrpav  So what you are trying to say is, the simulation works, but the real circuit doesn't work. Is it correct?

Comment: yes this is the case

Comment: like a not gate

Comment: Thank you ,probably by trying to make the question simple i made it worst. I am trying to build a not gate using 2n2222 . so i can trigger the 2n2222 with 3.3v from arduino/raspberry and by this i can trigger a relay board that the enable pin has a negative logic. So the relay board that i try to control need 5v to close then Ground to open my relay. And by these i tried to create this not gate so when i open the pinout of the controller then the enable pin of the relay goes to ground and the relay opens.Ofcourse the opposite part when the microcontroller goes to LOW the enable pin will get 5v

Comment: i do not want to go and place the relay also here , i just want to trigger the relay board which is already manufactured